# Usar vraptor-brutauth nas jsps

Tags: java, java-ee, autenticação, vraptor

Caros,

Estou com um problema que quando coloco uma regra com `@GlobalRule`, não consigo utilizar ela nas *jsps*..

Quando coloco apenas `${rules}` para listar o mapa de regras, a que tem o `@GlobalRule` não aparece. Quando tiro ela volta a aparecer..

Alguém ja passou por isso?